# Address of object in included layout in layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have one main_layout.xml file which includes two custom_layout.xml file then what should be the address of inner object in main_xml file?

**main_layout.xml**

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="#882" >

    <include 
        layout="@layout/custom_layout"
        android:id="@+id/b1" />

    <include 
        layout="@layout/custom_layout"
        android:id="@+id/b2" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**custom_layout.xml**

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="#882">

    <Button 

        android:id="@+id/a1"
        android:layout_height="10px"
        android:layout_width="10px"
        android:text="first" />

    <Button

        android:id="@+id/a2"
        android:layout_height="10px"
        android:layout_width="10px"
        android:text="second" />

</LinearLayout>
```

So there would be four button in my main_layout. In Android app I need particular address like R.id.a1 which gives me two button's reference. Plz tell me how to get the first button in first time used custom_layout. (My try R.id.b1.a1 fails) 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
View view = findViewById(R.id.b1);

Button button = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.a1);
```

In this way you can refer to particular view Button.